What's the maximum number OFFSET and LIMIT can accept in PostgreSQL
Can OFFSET and LIMIT accept BIGINT size integer or just INTEGER?
(up to 2147483647 or 9223372036854775807)
I couldn't find any mention in postgresql documentation
I thought about this because user can send offset and limit parameters with a request and i am confused, whether should i accept int64 or int32

How long time would it take to try a query with 9223372036854775807 values? (Using an empty table.) https://dbfiddle.uk/KRQ5mC7Z

How many rows can the query produce? Remember that in order for LIMIT/OFFSET to make sense, you must order the complete query result first. (Working with OFFSET is seldomly advisable by the way. I don't think I have ever used it even once in the last thirty years.)

What's the actual problem behind this question? OFFSET  N LIMIT M gets progressively slower because the database has to calculate the N rows before skipping them. You really don't want any client to make API requests that results in thousands of rows just to retrieve 50 in the middle.

I agree to you all, this is just for proof of concept, the code is not going to production

It does accept bigint, not just int so you need GO's int64. PostgreSQL sometimes calls bigint an int8 but that's in bytes - times 8 bits per byte gives you a 64-bit integer.
The doc on select..limit does keep quiet about it but it's easy enough to find out:
demo at db<>fiddle
create table t(c)as values (1),(2);
select*from t limit 32767--upper smallint limit 
              offset 32767;
select*from t limit 2147483647--upper integer limit 
              offset 2147483647;
select*from t limit 9223372036854775807--upper bigint limit
              offset 9223372036854775807;

All of these work fine and it's beyond bigint where it starts complaining:
select*from t limit 9223372036854775808--right above upper bigint limit
              offset 9223372036854775808;


ERROR:  bigint out of range


Limit above your number of rows does nothing, and offset beyond what you have just produces an empty structure.
What's more worrying is a client not using limit and offset, just requesting as much as db can offer. Offsetting through the majority of what the db has to process is just wasteful. The doc warns about over- and undershooting your limits:

The query optimizer takes LIMIT into account when generating query plans, so you are very likely to get different plans (yielding different row orders) depending on what you give for LIMIT and OFFSET. Thus, using different LIMIT/OFFSET values to select different subsets of a query result will give inconsistent results unless you enforce a predictable result ordering with ORDER BY. This is not a bug; it is an inherent consequence of the fact that SQL does not promise to deliver the results of a query in any particular order unless ORDER BY is used to constrain the order.
The rows skipped by an OFFSET clause still have to be computed inside the server; therefore a large OFFSET might be inefficient.

Postgres is capped at about 4e9 pages per table, and a table without any columns would need that much to store around 1e12 rows. That means the highest amount of rows in a single table is at one-millionth of how much limit and offset allow you to skip. You'd have to apply some very liberal joins, unions, partitioning and inheritance to run out of that and require numeric-sized skips, at which point I think you have bigger problems to deal with.
If you're using limit..offset for pagination, you could consider alternatives. Keyset pagination (sometimes confusingly called cursor pagination even though it doesn't use a SQL cursor) lets you save all the compute you'd normally spend calculating a large set of rows, just so that limit..offset can discard a bunch in the front and back. With keyset pagination you can instead jump right to the page you want.

Whenever the documentation fails, you can look at the source. The grammar only holds a clue in a comment:

We need FCONST as well as ICONST because values that don't fit in the platform's "long", but do fit in bigint, should still be accepted here. (This is possible in 64-bit Windows as well as all 32-bit builds.)

The Query struct is a bit more open about it (int8 expr):
    Node       *limitOffset;    /* # of result tuples to skip (int8 expr) */
    Node       *limitCount;     /* # of result tuples to return (int8 expr) */

Further:
node->offset = DatumGetInt64(val);


You may want to rephrase this: "You can use pretty arbitrary numbers there without worrying about performance." I'm not sure what you mean by that, and, as you mention right after, OFFSET and LIMIT can severely impact performance.

@Peter Thanks for pointing that out - I've removed it for now and I'll just replace it with a doc quote. What I wanted to underline is performance still comes from the query you're running and there's no way any combination of over/undershot limits would somehow make it cost more than the unconstrained version. Still, most of the time performance of queries where you use limit..offset is only compared to queries with some other kind of limit, rather than the full, unconstrained query, and saying you can bump them up and down freely does sound controversial.

Thank you very much for helpful answer and useful recommendations.
I didn't think about directly testing against the database, been exhausted last days :D
